# How do I write the code in Python for this slope

Tags: python

```
x1 = input('0.0')
x2 = input('5.6')
y1 = input('2.3')
y2 = input('6.6')

slope = (y2-y1 / x2-x1)

print("The Slope is ")
```

I have this write but every time I run it it returns a value of 0.0

Comment: `print("The Slope is {}".format(slope))`

Comment: `input` will ask the user for input. If you want to convert from a string to a float, use `float`, or simply write down the floating number, as in `x2 = 5.6`. In addition, your formula is incorrect; division has a higher precedence than subtraction, so you need additional parentheses.

Comment: Look at [what the input function does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) - it asks users what to assign to those variables. If you changed your code so that those lines were just `x1 = 0.0`, `x2 = 5.6` etc then your code would work. To ask a user for those values you'd change those lines to `x1 = float(input("Enter x1: "))`, so that the user could enter their own values.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would advice to use `raw_input` rather than `input`.
2. If you use python 2.x, `/` is floor division if both arguments are `int`, so to be on the save side make sure the input is converted to `float`.
3. Be careful with operation order of `+` and `/`: If `+` should be evaluated before `/` you need to put it in `()`
4. You need to print the variable `slope`.

So:

```
x1 = float(raw_input('x1'))  # point 1 and point 2 (conversion to float)
x2 = float(raw_input('x2'))
y1 = float(raw_input('y1'))
y2 = float(raw_input('y2'))

slope = (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)  # point 3: () are needed here

print("The slope is {0}".format(slope))  # point 4
```

Comment: I’d make it a function to not repeat 4 Times’.

Comment: @AntonvBR I agree with you, however, given the level of the question it might be that the OP is not yet familiar with function definitions, so I decided not to add further complexity.

Comment: `raw_input` is Python 2, `print()` is Python 3.